# How to change the default Storage Pool from libvirt?

Tags: kvm-virtualization, libvirt, virsh

I'm trying to use a different Storage Pool on KVM in order to store the virtual disks of my VMs and also the ISOs from the operating systems which I'm using.

**For example:** I want to use the directory `/media/work/kvm` which is mounted over `/dev/sda5`, as the default Storage Pool for all future situations

To configure, create and start a new storage pool, it is pretty easy, but a least in Ubuntu, it doesn't matter if I'm selecting and ISO from a different storage pool, **Virtual Machine Manager** always points me to the default Storage Pool (`/var/cache/libvirt`) as the storage where the virtual disks from my VMs will be created.

How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Before following the steps, be sure that you are running these commands as normal user and that your user belongs to the group `libvirtd` (on some systems `libvirt`).

Here are the following commands which I used:

**Listing current pools:**

```
$ virsh pool-list
    
Name                 State      Autostart 
-------------------------------------------
default              active     yes
```

**Destroying pool:**

```
$ virsh pool-destroy default
Pool default destroyed
```

**Undefine pool:**

```
$ virsh pool-undefine default
Pool default has been undefined
```

**Creating a directory to host the new pool (if it does not exist):**

```
$ sudo mkdir /media/work/kvm
```

**Defining a new pool with name "default":**

```
$ virsh pool-define-as --name default --type dir --target /media/work/kvm
Pool default defined
```

**Set pool to be started when libvirt daemons starts:**

```
$ virsh pool-autostart default
Pool default marked as autostarted
```

**Start pool:**

```
$ virsh pool-start default
Pool default started
```

**Checking pool state:**

```
$ virsh pool-list
Name                 State      Autostart 
-------------------------------------------
default              active     yes
```

From now, when creating virtual machines, Virtual Machine Manager will inform you that the *.img file (virtual disk of your VM), will be saved at /media/work/kvm.

Comment: `virsh pool-destroy default` results in `error: Storage pool not found: no storage pool with matching name 'default'`

Answer (score 8):

If you just want to change the image path, you can also edit the storage path in the `default` pool by running:

```
$ virsh pool-edit default
```

The above command will open the `default` pool xml in an editor (vim/nano), now:

1. edit the path
2. save the changes and
3. restart `libvirt` service

Comment: `virsh pool-edit default` results in `error: Storage pool not found: no storage pool with matching name 'default'`

Comment: @Vince that means your default storage pool doesn't exist, what version of libvirt are you using?

Comment: you can create a default pool as mentioned in @ivanleoncz 's answer: https://serverfault.com/a/840520/398346

Comment: Using `dpkg -l | grep libvirt` shows 6.0.0-0ubuntu8.10. The pools are there, but I can't see them unless I use `sudo`.  I haven't run virt-manager with `sudo`.

Comment: @Vince then that's a permission issue. Google 'virsh without sudo' and you should get some results to fix that.

Comment: I followed your advice. Apparently, it's by design. From the [virsh man page](https://libvirt.org/manpages/virsh.html#notes): "Most virsh commands require root privileges to run due to the communications channels used to talk to the hypervisor." So, I don't exactly have an issue. You're supposed to run `virsh` with `sudo`.

Answer (score 3):

Aside from the reply above showing how todo it from the command line, you can also change this from virt-manager directly. In the main virt-manager window, go to the menu 'Edit -> Host Details'. In the dialog box that appears, switch to the 'Storage' tab. You can now delete the 'default' storage pool and create a new storage pool to replace it.

Comment: I don't know why, Daniel, but I tried this solution before, and unfortunately, it didn't worked here on Virtual Machine Manager (Ubuntu Trusty Tahr - 14.04)...

Comment: The Edit menu doesn't have a "Host Details" option. It has a "Preferences" option, but there's no "Storage" tab. Virtual Machine Manager 2.2.1.

Comment: It is called "Connection details" these days.

Answer (score 2):

From the GUI, there doesn't seem to be a way to do it without an existing VM.

1. Select a VM
2. Select "Connection Details" from the Edit menu
3. Click the Storage tab
4. Select the default pool
5. Click the *Stop Pool* button

   - It looks like a horizontal line inside a broken circle
6. Click the *Delete Pool* button

   - It looks like a trash can
7. Click the pool you want to make your default or add a new pool you want to use as your default
8. If the pool was in use, you'll have to click the *Stop Pool* button again
9. Change the name of the pool to "default"
10. Click Apply

From the command line, the procedure described by ivanleoncz should work, but you'll need to run the commands with `sudo` in order for `virsh` to show any pools.

**Update**: It's apparently by design that you can't get the list of pools without `sudo`. According to [the virsh man page](https://libvirt.org/manpages/virsh.html#notes):

> Most virsh commands require root privileges to run due to the communications channels used to talk to the hypervisor.